# Ignores mouse input for periods at a time

Tags: 20.04, mouse

Fairly fresh 20.04 installation, and my mouse worked fine a week ago, but at some point the mouse started acting up. I usually discovers it by clicking and nothing happens. Then I click again, and nothing happens. Then I start clicking frantically, and at some point, it registers. It's not like the clicks are buffered and then fired all at once; it simply ignores mouse input for a few hundred milliseconds, and then it's back to normal. It looks like it does this every few seconds.

I recently started running the FS-UAE Amiga emulator, but now it does this even when FS-UAE isn't running, so I don't know if it has something to do with that.

This is really annoying. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it a USB mouse or a wireless with battery?  If battery could just be a weak or loose battery.  Wired mouse cable might broken or USB plug can be acting up.  Can also just be dirt/dust/hair inside of mouse.  Probably more wonky mouse than wonky Ubuntu.

Comment: If it's not the battery, do you see any input if you run`xev`?